# python: How do you print to a new line

Tags: python, newline

I am trying to print to a new line in python.

I tried:

```
print text '\n', sentiment '\n', score
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: That's because `print text '\n'` is not legal Python syntax. Look up string concatenation.

Comment: You just need more commas, or some explicit concatenation, or...

Comment: I didn't know I had to concatenate in the '\n'. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to concatenate the `\n` to the text:

```
print text + '\n', sentiment + '\n', score
```

Comment: Or just use separate print statements.

Comment: Or do it the flexible way: `print '{0}\n{1}\n{2}'.format(text, sentiment, score)`.

Comment: @Matthias That is certainly a valid way to do it, but I personally feel it should be avoided if possible. I think that method looks cluttered and is difficult to read what the output will be at a glance.

Comment: @zephyr: If I use `format` I know that I have full control over the output. I dislike the other method. Personal styles are different.